# 本 pronunciation

Tags: kanji, pronunciation

I was learning the kanji 本 and read the following line:

> Counter - (Sometimes pronounced ぼん or ぽん) - counter for long cylindrical things....

So my question is, when do you pronounce this as a ぼん or a ぽん? 
Does this depend on the item or is this a dialect-specific situation?

Comment: I found this linked in a different question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Euphonic_changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 本 is used as a counter, you only use ぼん/ぽん in the following situations:

> 一本{いっぽん}、三本{さんぼん}、六本{ろっぽん}、八本{はっぽん}、十本{じゅっぽん}

All other pronunciations use ほん. This works for bigger numbers as well:

> 八十本{はちじゅっぽん}、百六本{ひゃくろっぽん}、etc.